# Remove mysterious <TextNode textContent="\n "> with javaScript

Tags: javascript

I've got a div with two children, one `<h2>` and one `<ul>`.

My problem is that when I check .length of my div, by doing `document.getElementById('wrap').childNodes.length`, I get 5 instead of 2. And if I run `console.log` on `childNodes` I get this:

```
[<TextNode textContent="\n ">, h2, <TextNode textContent="\n ">, ul, <TextNode textContent="\n ">]
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Indenting my code has never before affected the length of the childNodes.

If I type everything on one row (as one long word) I get rid of all `<TextNode>` and it counts to 2 as it should and not 5.

I've got no idea what's wrong, but I figured I need to remove all empty textnodes. 
Which way would be the best to do this?

Thanks heaps

Ps. These `<TextNode textContent="\n ">` occurs all over the document, so I need to remove them all, not only in this particular div.

Comment: Nothing's wrong. That's exactly what's supposed to happen.

Comment: but earlier (i checked two other scripts), if i had a div that looked like this, i would get 2 children, and when i used .lastChild i would get 'ul' and not 'textnode'.. 

to reach the ul i now have to type .childNodes[3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox, right? [Firefox will treat whitespace as a textnode](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml). There's nothing you can do about it apart from code around them. Or, you could completely get rid of all whitespace, but I'm betting that's not an option. It's part of what makes writing webpages so, er, fun :-)

Comment: i tested firefox and safari, theyre the same = counts 5
ie = 2.

youd think that eventho it treats them as textnodes, they shouldnt be counted as an actual childnode, but instead just be ignored

Comment: Yep. At least some consistency would be nice either way. Normally I shy away from saying "use X framework", but they can help smooth out these weird wrinkles. If it's a massive problem, try jQuery or prototype or moo or one of those big ones. Otherwise, a bit of nodeType checking should get you sorted again.

Comment: It's not just Firefox. It's basically every browser other than IE (Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, Konqueror, Epiphany, ...). Try it in your favorite browser: http://jsbin.com/ozuwac shocking to see that IE9 still does this, even when presented with a modern doctype.

Answer (score 3):

with plain old js, this  would be

```
    function removeEmptyTextNodes(elem){
        var children = elem.childNodes;
        var child;
        var len = children.length;
        var i = 0;
        var whitespace = /^\s*$/;
        for(; i < len; i++){
            child = children[i];
            if(child.nodeType == 3){
                if(whitespace.test(child.nodeValue)){
                    elem.removeChild(child);
                    i--;
                    len--;
                }
            }else if(child.nodeType == 1){
                removeEmptyTextNodes(child);
            }
        }
    }

    removeEmptyTextNodes(document.body);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to remove any extra text nodes (although there are time when you should - for performance reasons).  You should always check for the NodeType when viewing the property ChildNodes.

Here is a link that should help:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1950641247

EDIT:

Here is a page that has some prototype code that should help:

http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/329/finding-html-elements-using-javascript-nextsibling-and-previoussibling

Here is the code from the link above:

```
Object.prototype.nextObject = function() {
    var n = this;
    do n = n.nextSibling;
    while (n && n.nodeType != 1);
    return n;
}

Object.prototype.previousObject = function() {
    var p = this;
    do p = p.previousSibling;
    while (p && p.nodeType != 1);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: well, i've used .lastChild before without any problems, and now, all of a sudden, instead of returning the actual last child, it gives me an empty textnode?

so instead of using .childNodes like i've always been doing, ur saying i should now also check the nodetype? 

this just feels so werid since childnodes always has returned the same in both ie and ff. 
now i will have to do a check to see if its ff or ie sort of :-/

Comment: Check the second link I provided.  It contains code that adds a function onto Object that allows you to filter the nodes by type.

Comment: @Isabell: This isn't something that changed recently.  This behavior has been in several browsers for a long time, and is completely valid per the spec.

Comment: @meow: *"well, i've used .lastChild before without any problems, and now, all of a sudden, instead of returning the actual last child, it gives me an empty textnode"* The text node (which isn't empty) ***is*** the actual last child.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it help:

```js
var listOfNodes=document.getElementById('parentNodeId');
nodeCount=0
for(i=0; i<listOfNodes.childNodes.length;i++){
    if(listOfNodes.childNodes[i].id != undefined){
        console.log(listOfNodes.childNodes[i].id)
        nodeCount++
    }
}
alert(nodeCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

`childNodes` will include text nodes, and particularly empty ones.

I always use the `children` array, as this only counts elements and not text nodes.